# Class has no initializers when using POP on a variable

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, protocols, viewcontroller

I want to apply protocol oriented programming in one of my applications. I created a protocol called "CustomAnchor" to get rid of the huge amount of commands, needed for Autolayout. But when I assign this protocol to a constant e.g profileImage, the Controller gets the following error:

> Class 'ProfileController' has no initializers

On the constant I get this gray warning:

> 1. Stored property 'profileImageView' without initial value prevents synthesized initializers

This is how the code looks like: (Use of POP at the bottom)

```
class ProfileController: UIViewController {

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.navigationItem.title = "Profil"
    self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
    fillData()
    setupView()
    confBounds()
 }

 func fillData() {
    profileImageView.image = UIImage(named: "test")
 }

 func setupView() {
    view.addSubview(profileImageView)
 }

 func confBounds() {
    profileImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    profileImageView.anchor(top: self.view.topAnchor, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 60, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 140, height: 140)
 }

 let profileImageView: UIImageView, CustomAnchor = { () -> UIImageView in
    let pView = UIImageView()
    pView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    pView.clipsToBounds = true
    pView.image = UIImage(named: "test")
    return pView
 }()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because no one answered I made a simple workaround and gave the Property to the Controller. Not really what I wanted (smooth POP) but it works..